# Capturing rich error details with addEventListener(error)

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm trying to add a global event listener to identify general errors. My website is intermittently failing to load certain dynamically-generated assets, and I'm trying to track the frequency of these errors.

I've added an event listener with useCapture so I can get all errors (including 404s on assets). But when I use this, I'm not getting a message like I would with *window.onerror* - just a reference to the object that triggered the error.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}, true)
</script>
```

Then I add a bogus asset just to trigger the error...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bogus.css">
```

This fires the event listener, but returns *undefined* as the *message*. Looking at the whole event object, it just seems to be a generic event. It points to the bogus.css object as the cause of the error, but gives no deeper information as to the nature of the error or status of that object.

Is there a better way to get this sort of information, or am I stuck with somewhat vague error information?